# well defined solution of heat equations

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes, schwartz-space

Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of rapidly decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\Phi_t$ be defined as

$$\Phi_t(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}},\quad t>0,\,\,x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

For any $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ we defined a function
$$u(t,x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Phi_t(x-y)f(y)\,dy,\quad t>0,x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

**First, I want to show $u$ is well defined.** My reasoning is that $\Phi_t$ is integrable and $f$ is a rapidly decreasing function and so is bounded. Hence the integral is well defined.

**Next, I want to show $u(t,\cdot)$ is in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$.** I am not sure what is the proper way to do this...is the convolution of a integral function and a schwartz function a schwartz function? How to verify an arbitrary function is indeed a Schwartz function? I saw this is somewhat mentioned in page 4 of the following
[enter link description here](http://users.math.yale.edu/~pg245/notes_pt3.pdf)

But they do not have an answer for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first you're right: Since $\Phi_t$ is a positive $L^1$ function with $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \Phi_t(x)dx=1$ for all $t> 0$, we get that the convolution integral is well defined and by Holder's inequality we get 
$$
|u(t,x)|\leq \sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}|f(y)|.
$$
Using the Dominated Convergence Theorem you can also see that if $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ then you can differentiate under the integral sign in the definition of $u$ and put all derivatives on $f$ to get that $u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and moreover 
$$
|\partial^\alpha_x u(t,x)|\leq \sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}} |\partial^\alpha f(y)|.
$$
The easiest way to get the decay is through the Fourier transform: We get that if we take the FT on the spatial variables, then $\hat{u}(t,\xi)=\hat{\Phi}_t(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)$ so that decay of $u(t,\cdot)$ is equivalent to differentiability of $\hat{u}$, which is "clear" since $\hat{\Phi}_t$ and $\hat{f}$ are smooth.

Comment: @ Jose27 Everything is good up to the second equation you wrote. I know is true. But I had trouble showing it, when I get to $\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{\mathbb{R}} n_t(x-y)\phi(y) dy\right|$. For the next step, I am not sure I should do integration by parts or make change of variable. Would be good if you could write out the detail for your 2nd inequality.

Comment: @ Jose27 For my last comment, I think I need to make change of variable $x-y=z$, so $dy=dz$, then do integration by parts, so I have $\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\int \Phi_t(z)f(x-z)dz\right|=\left|\int \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \Phi_t(z)f(x-z)dz\right|=\left| \int \Phi_t\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(x-z)\right|\le \sup_y |\partial f(y)|$. I am showing $\alpha=1$  case. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @math101: Almost correct:$$
\partial_x \int_\mathbb{R} \Phi_t (x-y)f(y)dy =\int_\mathbb{R} \partial_x\Phi_t(x-y) f(y)dy =-\int_\mathbb{R} \partial_y \Phi_t (x-y) f(y) dy=\int_\mathbb{R} \Phi_t(x-y) \partial_y f(y)dy.
$$
Where the second equality is the chain rule.

Comment: @ Jose27 Great explanation. Just one thing I need a bit detail for the last equality. How does the boundary term get vanish? I mean $\Phi_t(x-y)f(y)_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$, is it because $f$ is 0 at infinity? (Assume that we do not know much about $\Phi_t$ yet...)

Comment: @math101: You need to know something about $\Phi_t$ to conclude that the boundary terms vanish, but boundedness of $\Phi_t$ is enough since $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @ Jose27 ok. but my question is, does $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ implies $f$ vanishes at boundary?

Comment: @math101: The definition of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ implies that $f$ (and all its derivatives) vanish at $\pm \infty$, so yes.

Comment: @ Jose27   The Schwartz space of rapidly decreasing functions is the set of infinite differentiable $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ such that for all $m,n$,
  $|\phi|_{m,n}=:\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|x^m\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\phi(x)<\infty.$ How does this imply $f$ and all its derivatives vanish at $\pm\infty?$

Comment: @ Jose27 Earlier, we can invoke D.T.C to differentiate under integral sign since $\Phi_t$ is integrable and $f$ is bounded as it is a Schwartz function. Now,  what if I assume $f$ is in $L^p$ instead of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Can I still use the same reasoning?

Comment: @ Jose27 I feel the proof is the same for $f\in L^p$, because $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^p$, in other words, one can approximate $L^p$ functions using Schwartz functions. Correct me if I am wrong.